# Check If Cakephp update changes a variable in update

Tags: php, cakephp, web

I am wondering how I would go about performing a certain function if a particular field in cakephp save has been updated.

```
function edit($id = null) {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->Post->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
}
```

So - what I would like to do is be able to determine exactly what has been changed in the edit data ($this->data) and if a certain field has been changed send an email notification.  I know how to do the email part - but can't figure out how I would do it if lets say a select box was changed from Enabled to Disabled.  If changed from enabled to disabled email saying blah blah blah has been disabled.

Comment: In the above code, you are just trying to insert not to update.

Comment: So does that mean I am not editing correctly?  The code has been working just fine for me... I just assumed the cakephp save function was "smart" in that it would create a post or update it depending... I am still learning obviously!

Comment: If you are updating, you should set $this->Post->id first, right?

Comment: @habeebperwad no, if data[Post][id] is set, the corresponding post will be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read out the current saved content before you execute $this->Post->save() and compare the values after saving.

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {

  $oldValue=$this->Post->field('yourfield');

  if ($this->Post->save($this->data)) {
    if ($oldValue!=$this->data['Post']['yourfield'])
    {
      // do stuff
    }
    ...
```

As mark said, it would be cleaner to acomplish this direct in the model (e.g. in the case the data is changed in a different form)

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted it to. Thanks! I drew a blank on how to debug the $this->data to see the info because it was redirecting.. I just stopped the redirect so I could see the print_r of $this->data. Thanks again!

Comment: but shouldnt this be done in afterSave()? what if validation fails and the record is not modified?

Comment: you are right, but i described how to get this work in the controller - as i thought it would fit the question best. Of course it would be cleaner in the model, or as behaviour. I updated the answer to solve the validation problem.

Answer (score 3):

take a look at the loggable behavior:
https://github.com/alkemann/CakePHP-Assets/blob/master/models/behaviors/logable.php

it does exactly that in a clean way.

instead of putting it in this model, it would be a cleaner approach to create your own custom behavior. you should be able to modify it to your needs so it sends an email instead.

Comment: While this looks like it will do what I want - I think it might be overkill for my application. Great to know though in the future!!